# Application run different in debugger

Tags: ios

Currently working on an application and when run on the simulator or device behaves normally. When you close and reopen the application is behaving strangely.

For example I want to upload the application on the device (iPad), the first run everything is proceeding normally, then I close the application and it is open in the background and behaves strangely, cells no longer have same order.

If you delete the application and run it again after the device from Xcode everything returns to normal.

I tried both ways: Release and Debug.
   I checked the code and did deallocate.
  Can someone help me with more advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean pressing the Home button when saying "close". iOS transforms your app in a special suspended state and it seems you don't restore from it correctly. iOS sends a  `applicationWillEnterForeground` notification when your app is being restored from the suspended state and you may need to behave differently than app being launched the first time.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW21) you can find more info about this method.